# Json response on rails 6 from url with queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Only on Rails 6 when:

I receives a json response on pages with url like:

```
www.site.com/foo
```

and not when url is like:

```
www.site.com/foo?q=x
```

to reproduce:

1. rails new todo
2. rails scaffold Todo task:string
3. rails db:migrate
4. rails server
5. Create a task
6. In file show.json.jbuilder you'll see:

   json.partial! "todos/todo", todo: @todo
7. Go to show page (todo/1)
8. Type on browser's console to se json response:

   $.ajax({
     url: window.location.href + ".json",
     dataType: 'json',
     async: false
   });

When your url is "todo/1" jbuilder loads ok:

```
Started GET "/todos/1.json" for ::1 at 2019-10-28 13:55:54 -0300
Processing by TodosController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Todo Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "todos".* FROM "todos" WHERE "todos"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/todos_controller.rb:67:in `set_todo'
  Rendering todos/show.json.jbuilder
  Rendered todos/_todo.json.jbuilder (Duration: 1.0ms | Allocations: 125)
  Rendered todos/show.json.jbuilder (Duration: 2.2ms | Allocations: 306)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 3.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Allocations: 1565)
```

[image]

But if your url is "todo/1?q=foo" you have no data:

```
Started GET "/todos/1?q=foo.json" for ::1 at 2019-10-28 13:55:44 -0300
Processing by TodosController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"q"=>"foo.json", "id"=>"1"}
  Todo Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "todos".* FROM "todos" WHERE "todos"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/todos_controller.rb:67:in `set_todo'
  Rendering todos/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered todos/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.7ms | Allocations: 89)
Completed 200 OK in 25ms (Views: 21.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Allocations: 6547)
```

[image]

Obs: I opened this [rails github issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37577)

Answer (score 1):

In order to work in rails 6.0.0 we need to explicitly tell to use json format when the url has queries:

**todos_controller.rb**

change from:

```
def show 
end
```

to:

```
def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the request must be in the following form:

`www.site.com/foo.json?q=x`

If you want to pass parameters to the request, you can use the `data` parameter of ajax.

For instance:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/todos",
  type: "GET",
  data: {
    id: 1,
    q: "x"
  },
  success: function (response) {
    console.log(response.data)
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi Samy Kacimi, I tried this and didn't change. I also updated the question because this behavior is only presented on rails 6

Comment: What do the logs of your rails server say when making the request ?

Comment: Good question. I updated my post above with this information. We can see that jbuilder doesn't compile in one of them